# Android NDK: programmatically determine screen's frames per second (fps)

Tags: android, user-interface, android-ndk, frame-rate

I'm writing some animation code that will run in Android's NDK environment. and I am using Choreographer to learn when new frames are drawn. Is there a way to learn what the screen's frame rate is programmatically? I know how to get it using adb, so I know the datum is available somehow. But how can I get the FPS using C++?

Comment: Your `frameCallback` is given _"the time that the frame is being rendered as nanoseconds in the CLOCK_MONOTONIC time base"_. Can't you use that to determine the framerate?